# regex validation not working (phone and name)

Tags: php, regex, validation

Even when I type in a not valid phone number, my regex validates it and shows the valid message. Any ideas whats going wrong?

```
<form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST">
Name (First Middlie  Last) : <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br />
Telephone Number : <input type="text" name="phone" value=""><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php } else {

extract($_REQUEST);

$phoneDashes = preg_replace("/\D/","", $phone);
$nameRegex =  $_POST['name'];

if(preg_match("/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/", $phoneDashes,$matches)) {
 echo "Valid phone number <br />";
   }
else {
   echo "Not a valid phone number <br />";
}

preg_match("/(^[\-a-z]+)\s([\-a-z])\s([\-a-z]+)$/i", $nameRegex,$names);

echo "Your name: $names[3], $names[2] $names[1] <br />";
echo "Your phone Number: $matches[1]-$matches[2]-$matches[3] <br />";

}

?>
```

Comment: What string do you use in `if` statement?

Comment: the phone number string? Is that where the problem is?

Comment: No, what value did you use to get wrong result?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$match = preg_match("/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/", $phoneDashes,$matches);
if($match) {
 echo "Valid phone number <br />";
   }
else {
   echo "Not a valid phone number <br />";
}
```

Comment: mmm.. nope that doesn't work either. No matter what i put in, it says valid number. Any more suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: awesome. yes it works. Would you like to help me on another php problem of mine? I'd be willing to work out a price if you are interested.

Comment: sure. give me your skype/mail

Comment: sent you single email. You can delete your email (comment) now

Answer (score 0):

You need `^` and `$` anchors. Try this:

```php
if (preg_match('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $phoneDashes, $matches))
    // Valid phone number
else
    // Not valid phone number
```